# JavaScript function only affects first div with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I have part of a game where the cursor is supposed to "slow down" when it passes over certain divs. I'm using a function that can detect a collision with the div. This works fine when the cursor meets the first div, but it doesn't work at all on the second div.

[Check out this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sy1tg36/) for a better idea of what I'm talking about. Pass the cursor over the first white block (`class='thing'`) on the left and it slows down. Pass the cursor over the other block (also `class='thing'`), and nothing happens. I need this collision function to work on all divs where `class='thing'`.

**HTML**

```
<div id='cursor'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class='thing' style='width:70px; height:70px; background: #fff; position: absolute; bottom: 350px; right: 800px; z-index: -1;'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class='thing' style='width:70px; height:70px; background: #fff; position: absolute; bottom: 200px; right: 400px; z-index: -1;'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
(function collide(){
var newInt = setInterval(function() {
function collision($cursor, $thing) {
    var x1 = $cursor.offset().left;
    var y1 = $cursor.offset().top;
    var h1 = $cursor.outerHeight(true);
    var w1 = $cursor.outerWidth(true);
    var b1 = y1 + h1;
    var r1 = x1 + w1;
    var x2 = $thing.offset().left;
    var y2 = $thing.offset().top;
    var h2 = $thing.outerHeight(true);
    var w2 = $thing.outerWidth(true);
    var b2 = y2 + h2;
    var r2 = x2 + w2;

    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    var varies = 12;    

    if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2){
    } else {
    varies = 200;
    console.log(varies);
    }
$xp += (($mouseX - $xp)/varies);
    $yp += (($mouseY - $yp)/varies);
    $("#cursor").css({left:$xp +'px', top:$yp +'px'}); 

}

$(collision($('#cursor'), $('.thing')));
//$('.result').text(collision($('#cursor'), $('.thing')));

}, 20);
})();
```

Comment: $thing is a collection

Comment: Avoid using `setInterval` for animations because it can cause (and, actually, in your JSFiddle causes) lags. Use `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/jquerycollision/code/ci/master/tree/jquery-collision.js

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thanks for the link! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$thing` is a collection of elements, like you want, but the problem here is that you ask specific attributes from `$thing` like `offset().left;`,  which can not return more than one number, therefor it just takes the first. What you should do instead is use an `.each()` function to loop over all the elements in `$thing`.

```
$thing.each( function( index, element ){
    //your code for each thing here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It sort of works now. I've seem to run into what appears to be a bug. If you take a look at this updated jsfiddle:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/5sy1tg36/8/)
You'll see:
`if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2){
            varies = 200;
            changeMouseSpeed();
        } else {
            varies = 12;
            changeMouseSpeed();
            console.log('hit');
        }
`
But if I switch around the values in `varies` it won't work at all.

Comment: Could you make that a separate question? Sounds interesting!

Comment: Perhaps you should put `varies` outside the loop.

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I just made a new question addressing this problem. The new question is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32895727/is-this-a-bug-javascript-conditional)

Comment: However, your answer does solve the problem I had with looping through the collection, so I'll mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

When you are selecting element by class name(in your case using `.thing`) in jQuery you will get an array of elements and `collision()` function will take first element in an array. so to overcome this you need to uniquely select both the elements this can be done using id as a selector,You can change your code like below to work it as expected

```
<div id='track'>
    <div class = 'container'>
        <div id='cursor' class='cursor'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class='thing' id="a1" style='width:70px; height:70px; background: #fff; position: absolute; bottom: 175px; right: 400px; z-index: -1;'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class='thing' id="a2"  style='width:70px; height:70px; background: #fff; position: absolute; bottom: 100px; right: 200px; z-index: -1;'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


(function cursorMapping(){

var $mouseX = 0, $mouseY = 0;
var $xp = 0, $yp =0;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $mouseX = e.pageX;
    $mouseY = e.pageY;    
});

function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coor = "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y;
}

var timestamp = null;
var lastMouseX = null;
var lastMouseY = null;

var mrefreshinterval = 500; // update display every 500ms
 var lastmousex=-1; 
 var lastmousey=-1;
 var lastmousetime;
 var mousetravel = 0;
 var lastmousetravel = 0;

var speed;
var marker1 = 1;
var marker2 = 1;

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    marker1;
    marker2;
}, 20);

$(function() {

    var $speedometer = $('#speed'),
         _speed = 0; 

    $('#track').cursometer({
        onUpdateSpeed: function thisSpeed(speed) {
            _speed = speed;
            $speedometer.text(Math.ceil(speed * 100)/100);
        },
        updateSpeedRate: 20
    });

});

var thisInterval = setInterval(function FXInterval(){
    speed = $('#speed').text();
        $('#cursor').css({'background-color': '#CE7A7A'});
}, 20);

 $('html').mousemove(function(e) {
     var mousex = e.pageX;
     var mousey = e.pageY;
     if (lastmousex > -1)
         mousetravel += Math.max( Math.abs(mousex-lastmousex), Math.abs(mousey-lastmousey) );
     lastmousex = mousex;
     lastmousey = mousey;
     var speed = lastmousex + lastmousey;

    setTimeout(function(){
        lastmousetravel = mousetravel;
    }, 20);
 });

(function collide(){
var newInt = setInterval(function() {
function collision($cursor, $thing) {
    var x1 = $cursor.offset().left;
    var y1 = $cursor.offset().top;
    var h1 = $cursor.outerHeight(true);
    var w1 = $cursor.outerWidth(true);
    var b1 = y1 + h1;
    var r1 = x1 + w1;
    var x2 = $thing.offset().left;
    var y2 = $thing.offset().top;
    var h2 = $thing.outerHeight(true);
    var w2 = $thing.outerWidth(true);
    var b2 = y2 + h2;
    var r2 = x2 + w2;

    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    var varies = 12;    

    if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2){
    } else {
    varies = 200;
    console.log(varies);
    }
$xp += (($mouseX - $xp)/varies);
    $yp += (($mouseY - $yp)/varies);
    $("#cursor").css({left:$xp +'px', top:$yp +'px'}); 
}
$(collision($('#cursor'), $('#a1')));
$(collision($('#cursor'), $('#a2')));

}, 20);
})();

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is definitely the most direct solution to my problem. However, I'm going to use `.each()` because I'm less familiar with that and it's good for me to try different things.